# Создание удаленного репозитория без ssh без доступа к файлам

Tags: git

Существует ли способ создать репозиторий на удаленном сервере без подключения по ssh?
Говорят что такая возможность есть, но сколько не гуглил ничего подобного не нашел.

Там phpGit (его форк https://github.com/tpruvot/gitPhp), который уже давно загнулся. В самой веб-панели тоже нет никаких кнопок для добавления репозиториев (как на гитхабе или битбакете)

Comment: все зависит от типа сервера.

Comment: git это если упрощенно - набор файлов. Тип взаимодействия  с файловым хранилищем  не имеет значения, если есть права доступа. @KoVadim От типа сервера зависит только способ подключения к файловому хранилищу

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич в том, то и дело что доступов для подключения по ssh у меня нет. Если бы были, то сделал бы все как обычно - git init --bare

Comment: @XYZ а какие есть способы доступа к файловому хранилищу на сервере?

Comment: @KoVadim от какого сервера?

Comment: от типа используемого git сервера. То есть, gitolite, gitlab, github и тому подобное

Comment: @XYZ слово сервер есть в Вашем вопросе.

Comment: @KoVadim там phpGit (его форк https://github.com/tpruvot/gitPhp), который уже давно загнулся. В самой веб-панели тоже нет никаких кнопок для добавления репозиториев (как на гитхабе или битбакете)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич никаких. Доступы только у сисадмина

Comment: @XYZ знаете ту шутку про "нет ручек, нет мультиков". Это про Ваш вопрос.

Comment: *Доступы только у сисадмина* — дело за малым: осталось взломать сервер и создать там всё, что требуется. хоть «с ssh», хоть «без».

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич знаю))) Просто решил спросить(вдруг я что-то не до конца понимаю) прежде чем начинать спорить

Answer (score 2):

Не существует. Git -- это набор команд, которые выполняются из командной строки, а доступа к командной строке у вас нет.

В принципе, если у вас есть доступ к заливке сайтов (например, по протоколу FTP или на сайте есть какой-то загрузчик файлов в админке), то можете локально создать репозиторий через `git init`, а потом перебросить файлы на сервер.

Это будет точно такой же результат, как будто вы выполнили такую команду на сервере.

Давайте обратим только внимание вот на что.

Во-первых, на сервере может оказаться, что и не установлен git -- вы об никак не знаете, верно?

А, во-вторых, как вы собираетесь потом пользоваться этим репозиторием? Через exec выполнять команды на сервере через веб-админку?

По-моему, так себе идея. Лучше не поскупитесь на собственный хостинг, где вы сможете полноценно пользоваться сервером.